# Extract data from xml stored as nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing

I have to extract email `Subject` from an `XML` stored as `nvarchar`.

I'm using this query :

```
SELECT rtrim((SELECT CAST(
                    SUBSTRING(
                        [XML]
                        ,patindex('%<SUBJECT>%', [XML])
                        ,patindex('%</SUBJECT>%', [XML])-patindex('%<SUBJECT>%', [XML])+len('</SUBJECT>')
                    ) as XML).value('(/SUBJECT/OPTION)[1]','nvarchar(2000)')
            FROM   dbo.Mails 
)) as SUBJECT
```

What this query do is extracting at first the string which contains email subject (`<SUBJECT>....</SUBJECT>`) which I convert to XML and then get the Subject value using `value` function of XML.

This works fine, but in some cases the XML is not well formed and the parsing fails. Example :

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML =  '<SUBJECT>
      <OPTION CONSTRAINT="MASTER.IN_TITLE = ''  OR  MASTER.IN_LASTNAME = ''"><![CDATA[DÃ©couvrez nos offres de location]]>
      </OPTION>
      <OPTION CONSTRAINT="IN_TITLE <> '' AND MASTER.IN_LASTNAME <> ''"><![CDATA[~IN_TITLE~ ~IN_LASTNAME~, dÃ©couvrez nos offres de location]]>
      </OPTION>
   </SUBJECT>'

select rtrim((@XMLData).value('(/SUBJECT/OPTION)[1]','nvarchar(2000)') )
```

Here in the `Option` attribute `Constraint` I have a special character `<`, If I try to escape this character it escapes all other character and I lost the XML structure. So how to escape it?

Another example is this :

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML =  '<SUBJECT>
      <OPTION NAME="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[~(IF((IN_TITLE<>'' AND IN_LASTNAME<>''),IN_TITLE&' '&IN_LASTNAME&',',''))~ nos plus belles rÃ©alisations de 2015]]>
      </OPTION>
   </SUBJECT>'

select rtrim((@XMLData).value('(/SUBJECT/OPTION)[1]','nvarchar(2000)') )
```

Here I got error near `&IN_LASTNAME&` but I thought we don't need to escape special character in `CDATA`!

Does anyone have a solution to avoid these erros in parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are these XMLs generated? Is this under your control? The three *characters of evil "**<, > and &**"* must be treated specially, either `CDATA` or escaped. If the XML is generated properly it should **not be possible to get them in forbidden places**...

Here are two working examples. The second is identical with Rhys Jones...
In the first example I replace the "<>" with `&lt;&gt;`.

Btw: As you are dealing with other special characters obviously, you should mark your strings with `N'string'` to read it as `unicode`.

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML =  REPLACE(N'<SUBJECT>
      <OPTION CONSTRAINT="MASTER.IN_TITLE = ''  OR  MASTER.IN_LASTNAME = ''"><![CDATA[DÃ©couvrez nos offres de location]]>
      </OPTION>
      <OPTION CONSTRAINT="IN_TITLE <> '' AND MASTER.IN_LASTNAME <> ''"><![CDATA[~IN_TITLE~ ~IN_LASTNAME~, dÃ©couvrez nos offres de location]]>
      </OPTION>
   </SUBJECT>','<>','&lt;&gt;');

select rtrim((@XMLData).value('(/SUBJECT/OPTION)[1]','nvarchar(2000)') );
GO

DECLARE @XMLData XML =  N'<SUBJECT>
      <OPTION NAME="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[~(IF((IN_TITLE<>'''' AND IN_LASTNAME<>''''),IN_TITLE&'' ''&IN_LASTNAME&'','',''''))~ nos plus belles rÃ©alisations de 2015]]>
      </OPTION>
   </SUBJECT>'

select rtrim((@XMLData).value('(/SUBJECT/OPTION)[1]','nvarchar(2000)') )
```

Answer (score 2):

The extra '<' in the '<>' character combination is preventing the conversion to XML. So I suggest you get rid of the '<>' before converting the string to XML. In my example I am replacing it with '!='. I realize this may not fit your situation exactly since you need to deal with the results from a query with the potential for multiple rows rather than just a variable, but hopefully this will give you some ideas.

```
DECLARE @badStringPos int

DECLARE @stringXMLData varchar(500)=  '<SUBJECT>
      <OPTION CONSTRAINT="MASTER.IN_TITLE = ''  OR  MASTER.IN_LASTNAME = ''"><![CDATA[DÃ©couvrez nos offres de location]]>
      </OPTION>
      <OPTION CONSTRAINT="IN_TITLE <> '' AND MASTER.IN_LASTNAME != ''"><![CDATA[~IN_TITLE~ ~IN_LASTNAME~, dÃ©couvrez nos offres de location]]>
      </OPTION>
   </SUBJECT>'

declare @XMLData xml

set @badStringPos = patindex('%<>%', @stringXMLData)

while @badStringPos <> 0
begin
    set @stringXMLData = left(@stringXMLData, patindex('%<>%', @stringXMLData) - 1) + '!=' +
                         right(@stringXMLData, len(@stringXMLData) - (patindex('%<>%', @stringXMLData) + 1))
    set @badStringPos = patindex('%<>%', @stringXMLData)
end

set @XMLData = convert(xml, @stringXMLData)

select rtrim((@XMLData).value('(/SUBJECT/OPTION)[1]','nvarchar(2000)') )
```

One option would be to iterate over you query results with a cursor.

Comment: Your idea is correct in principle, but it was easier to replace the `<>` with `&lt;&gt;`. The advantage is, that you would not change the content...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Replacing the `<>` did the job. But I just used the `Replace` function as suggested by @Shnugo.

Comment: Wow. @Shnugo's answer is much better. I wanted to use the REPLACE function, but the SSMS Intellisense/Tooltip deceived me into thinking I could only replace 1 character with 1 other character. How should I interpret "replace(expression nvarchar(1), expression nvarchar(1), expression nvarchar(1)) RETURNS nvarchar(1)"?

Comment: I should have check MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to work out what was wrong here - you've got single quotes inside your string (2nd example), they need to be doubled up;

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML =  '<SUBJECT>
      <OPTION NAME="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[~(IF((IN_TITLE<>'' AND IN_LASTNAME<>''),IN_TITLE&'' ''&IN_LASTNAME&'','',''))~ nos plus belles rÃ©alisations de 2015]]>
      </OPTION>
   </SUBJECT>'

select rtrim((@XMLData).value('(/SUBJECT/OPTION)[1]','nvarchar(2000)') )
```